# Have a custom print button for report viewer?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, report

Is it possible to have a button on my webpage that will print the report viewer report? The built in button requires admin rights and report viewer installed on each machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504567/Print-button-and-date-picker-in-SSRS-reports-for-n

i hope this should help u. Please see if its help you